# PHP PDO проверка на SQL инъекцию

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection

Все привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли в данный код внедрить SQL инъекцию?

```
$query = $pdo ->query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `public` = 1 ORDER BY pubdate DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Нет, нельзя внедрить.

Comment: сложно что-то внедрить в код, если он не оперирует данными, которые берёт из вне

Comment: @СергейМишин сложно но возможно? Каким образом это можно сделать если никаких входных данных нет?

Comment: @MoloF для вас русский наверное не родной. Это фигура речи, в основе которой лежит сарказм

Comment: @Ипатьев родной, видимо я не так понял просто, не увидел конкретики, но спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: Спасибо большое всем!

Answer (score 0):

С целью исключения инъекций SQL (и об этом не паранойить), применяется функция специальная для экранирования. В неё передаются знаки мест данных вставки, в аргумент следующий, типы данных.

```
$number = (int) 5;
// Знаки не известные означают переменные в порядке соответствующем вызову функции следующей
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT ?")){
     // Здесь указывается тип данных, i - Значит int
     if ($stmt->bind_param('i', $number) == true){
          if ($stmt->execute() == true){
             $return = true;
          }
     }
}
```

Используется класс mysqli (стиль ООП)
Подробней об функциях написано в документации по PHP

Comment: Вообще-то автор использует PDO, а не mysqli и организация кода в целом бессмысленная (все эти if и return не несут ни малейшего смысла) но хотя бы спасибо за использование подготовленных выражений